# mysql syntax error with inserting website post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm coding server side of a web site and i used this for storing the post

```
if(!(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `post-data`(`site`, `source`, `meta-desc`, `title`, `figure`, `post`,`date`, `tags`, `category`) VALUES ('$this->site','$url','$this->meta_desc','$this->title','$this->figure',htmlentities($this->body),NOW(),'','')"))){
            echo mysql_error();
            die("DB_in_post Error");}
```

I had no problem since when i was testing a sample post i got mysql syntax error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> as a person ' at Line 20

when i use htmlentities i see this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hello', 'world', 'foo' => 'bar');
>
> if you want' at line

[Post_Link](http://s17.postimage.org/j3ahq6ljj/Capture.jpg) this is an image from the part of post that is making error the post is about coding

so any idea what should i do?

Comment: You didn't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` properly if an unescaped quote made it into the query. Please post more code.

Comment: You're using `htmlentities` in the middle of a string and you're using object variables `$this->etc` in the middle of a string.

Comment: `htmlentities()`, as the name suggests, is for **HTML** ;-P

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a quoting issue by your call to `htmlentities()` (which I changed to `mysql_real_escape_string()`)

```
"INSERT INTO `post-data`
     (`site`, `source`, `meta-desc`, `title`, `figure`, `post`,`date`, `tags`, `category`) 
VALUES (
    '$this->site',
    '$url',
    '$this->meta_desc',
    '$this->title',
    '$this->figure',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->body) ."',
    NOW(),
    '',
    ''
)"
```

Comment: it worked for the first error but now is another error i edited the question

Comment: You'll need to post your query *after* it has been parsed by PHP

Comment: sry but i think i didn't get it what should i do this code worked for all of tests that i had but just this post made error

Comment: Apparently one of the values in your variables break SQL. We can't figure that out until we see the actual SQL query.

Comment: [Post_Link](http://s17.postimage.org/j3ahq6ljj/Capture.jpg) this is an image from the part of post that is making error the post is about coding

Comment: Is there any way to get the actual SQL? `echo "INSERT INTO `post-data`
     (`site`, `source`, `meta-desc`, `title`, `figure`, `post`,`date`, `tags`, `category`) 
VALUES (
    '$this->site',
    '$url',
    '$this->meta_desc',
    '$this->title',
    '$this->figure',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->body) ."',
    NOW(),
    '',
    ''
)"`